# Perl, problems scrubbing a file with regex effeciently

Tags: regex, arrays, perl

First I will explain the problem my program attempts to solve. I have two input files, one contains lines of "good" numbers:

```
100000
100001
100002
100003
100004
```

The other file is a file of "raw" numbers that I want to check each line of and see if the line contains one of the "good" numbers above followed by 4 more numbers, the additional 4 numbers can be anything. so if the file containing the raw numbers is :

```
8881000001234
1000014321
999991000021234567
00234100001
1000041234
100002123
1000029876
```

after scrubbing with regex the matched numbers would be

```
1000001234
1000014321
1000021234
1000041234
1000029876
```

The way I have done this so far is to store the "good" numbers in an array then slurped the "raw" numbers into a scalar

```
my $FH
my@good_nums
open $FH, '<', 'good_numbers' or die $!;
while(<$FH>) { chomp; push @good_nums, $_; }
close $FH;

open $FH, '<', 'raw_numbers' or die $!;
my $raw_nums = do { local $/; <$FH> };
close $FH;
```

then with those I can do this :

```
my @matches;
foreach my $num (@good_nums) {
    push @matches, $raw_nums =~ /$num\d{4}/g;
}
```

So `@matches` contains the correct matches and this has been working well.

But now I have developed the need to also capture the lines from "raw" numbers that did not match. I can capture the non matching lines by putting the "raw" numbers into an array (instead of slurping them) and `join` the `@good_nums` array into a regex :

```
my $QRnums = '(?:' . (join '|', @good_nums) . ')';
$QRnums = qr/$QRnums/;

my @raw_nums;
open my $FH, '<', 'raw_numbers' or die $!;
while(<$FH>) { chomp; push @raw_nums, $_; }

my @matches;
my @junk;
for (@raw_nums) {   
    if ($_ =~ /($QRnums\d{4})/g) {
        push @matches, $1;
    } else {
        push @junk, $_;
    }
}
```

This is working but when I increase the number of lines in each file to 150,000 or more, the latter solution takes 4 or 5 times longer than the former solution. I know there must be another Perl solution that can solve my problem efficiently but I am at a loss. I am not very good with intermediate Perl and beyond.. Is there a better way to do this or can my first solution be rewritten so that I can obtain the non matches in an array too? Apart from needing to solve the problem explained in the opening of my post, I am open to anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only cache your regex one time, and then compare using `$_ =~ $QRnums`.

Additionally, there's no need to slurp your other file, just do line-by-line process instead.

```
my $QRnums = '(?:' . (join '|', @good_nums) . ')';
$QRnums = qr/($QRnums\d{4})/;

my @matches;
my @junk;

open my $FH, '<', 'raw_numbers' or die $!;
while (<$FH>) {
    chomp;
    if ($_ =~ $QRnums) {
        push @matches, $1;
    } else {
        push @junk, $_;
    }
}
```

Also, if your regex should be bounded to the start of the string `^`, then I would suggest that you add that: `$QRnums = qr/^($QRnums\d{4})/;`

**Addendum**

From [`perlop - Regexp Quote-Like Operators`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators)

> Since Perl may compile the pattern at the moment of execution of the `qr()` operator, using `qr()` may have speed advantages in some situations, notably if the result of `qr()` is used standalone:

and later:

> Precompilation of the pattern into an internal representation at the moment of `qr()` avoids a need to recompile the pattern every time a match `/$pat/` is attempted. (Perl has many other internal optimizations, but none would be triggered in the above example if we did not use `qr()` operator.)

Basically, because your `@good_nums` list was potentially very large, it made sense to cache that if we could so that it the regex test only needed to be compiled once.

Comment: Thanks this is a big help and is more efficient then what I was doing, if you could explain to me how caching works with regex and how my example was handling caching it would be a huge help to me. if it is too broad a topic, can you point me to any good references? thanks again.

Comment: Added a link to documentation about cached regex's.